# Lua "if...then" statement unresponsive

Tags: lua

I'm a newbie using LUA to make missions in 
Operation Flashpoint: Dragon Rising's mission editor. I've been trying to get the script down for about a week, I've googled, edited, and scoured the help index of the editor till it feels like my eyes are bleeding and it's all led to this.
I'm having an issue with this "if...then" statement not doing anything. First, here's the whole thing:

```
function onMissionStart()
OFP:showLetterBoxOsd(false);
OFP:allowPlayerMovement(true);
OFP:allowPlayerFire(true);
OFP:setObjectiveState("Wave1","IN_PROGRESS");
OFP:setObjectiveState("Wave2","IN_PROGRESS");
OFP:activateEntitySet("enemy1");
end --This all seems to work fine, nothing to see here.

--OFP:isAlive(name of unit or entity set)
function isAlive() --After naming this function, a pesky "'<name>' expected near 'if'" error dissapeared so thats nice.
if OFP:isAlive("enemy1") == (false) --This "if..Then" statement should spawn "enemy2" when "enemy1" dies.                   
then
OFP:activateEntitySet("enemy2");
end

if OFP:isAlive("enemy2") == (false)
then
OFP:setObjectiveState("Wave2","COMPLETED")
OFP:missionCompleted() 
end
end
```

Now here's what's giving me trouble:

```
function isAlive() 
if OFP:isAlive("enemy1") == (false)                  
then
OFP:activateEntitySet("enemy2");
end
```

This is supposed to spawn `enemy2` when `enemy1` dies, but in game it might as well not exist, it doesn't work.

This names my function, the next line was throwing `'<name>'` expected near `if` until I did.

```
function isAlive()
```

This should track whether `enemy1` is still alive, and if it returns a false it should spawn `enemy2`.

```
if OFP:isAlive("enemy1") == (false)                  
then
OFP:activateEntitySet("enemy2");
end
```

Comment: in which universe is Lua a "deadish language"?

Comment: I personally have only seen it in either old games or Computercraft for Minecraft. I've also has several people who work with code say as much. I am a noob though so it's likely Lua is in more places than I think.

Comment: Are you aware that functions might as well not exist unless they get called?

Comment: Isn't the "function isAlive()" a call? Or am I mistaken about what a call even is?

Comment: UPDATE: I figured out how to call the functions. It's still not spawning what I want when I want but I think I'll just have the waves spawn from a user activated object, might be easier.

Answer (score 0):

function onMissionStart ist most likely a function the game calls when the mission starts. I could not find any official reference manual but the game seems to have some event based scripting system.

The remaining code you provided probably only executed when the file is loaded and therefor without any effect during the game.

**Edit** due to comment:

```
function onMissionStart()
  OFP:showLetterBoxOsd(false);
  OFP:allowPlayerMovement(true);
  OFP:allowPlayerFire(true);
  OFP:setObjectiveState("Wave1","IN_PROGRESS");
  OFP:setObjectiveState("Wave2","IN_PROGRESS");
  OFP:activateEntitySet("enemy1");
end --This all seems to work fine, nothing to see here.
```

The above code defines the function onMissionStart(). It most likely implements a function that is called by the game, when the mission starts.

You added the following code if I'm not mistaken:

```
--OFP:isAlive(name of unit or entity set)
function isAlive() --After naming this function, a pesky "'<name>' expected near 'if'" error dissapeared so thats nice.
  if OFP:isAlive("enemy1") == (false) --This "if..Then" statement should spawn "enemy2" when "enemy1" dies.                   
then
OFP:activateEntitySet("enemy2");
end

if OFP:isAlive("enemy2") == (false)
then
OFP:setObjectiveState("Wave2","COMPLETED")
OFP:missionCompleted() 
end
end
```

This also defines a function. isAlive. But who calls that function and when?

I found a list of events in DROPP. I presume that's the mission editor thing you're talking about. On certain events it will run certain functions. Like onAllplayersDead() would be called if all players are dead.

Explaining this all would be beyond the scope of this community. Just read through all of http://www.suderman.com/OFPDR/DROPP/reference.html and all files in http://www.suderman.com/OFPDR/DROPP/download.html

```
EventScripts =  {
    onAllPlayersDead = 0,
    onArriveAtWaypoint = 0,
    onCmdCompleted = 0,
    onDeath = 0,
    onDespawnEntitySet = 0,
    onDespawnEntity = 0,
    onDismount = 0,
    onEnter = 0,
    onEnterRVPoint = 0,
    onFirepowerKill = 0,
    onHit = 0,
    onIdentified = 0,
    onIncap = 0,
    onLand = 0,
    onLeave = 0,
    onMissionStart = 0,
    onMobilityKill = 0,
    onMount = 0,
    onMultiplayerMissionLoaded = 0,
    onNoAmmo = 0,
    onNoAmmoAll = 0,
    onObjectDamage = 0,
    onObjectDamage = 0,
    onObjectiveCompleted = 0,
    onObjectiveFailed = 0,
    onObjectiveVisible = 0,
    onOffboardSupp = 0,
    onPinned = 0,
    onPlaceableKill = 0,
    onPlayEnter = 0,
    onPlayDone = 0,
    onPlayFailed = 0,
    onPlayInvalid = 0,
    onPvPMissionEnd = 0,
    onRespawn = 0,
    onSpawnedReady = 0,
    onSpeechEnd = 0,
    onSuppressed = 0,
    onSuspected = 0,
    onUnsuppressed = 0,
}
```

Comment: Are you implying I shouldn't start with onMissionStart()?

Comment: Sorry to spam, I pressed comment too early:

I tried cutting onMissionStart() out and it made nothing spawn. Additionally I tried combining the remaining script into the same block as onMissionStart() and it just made everything spawn at once. I think I may be too ignorant to understand why the rest of the code wouldn't have any effect during the game or what I should be doing about that.

Comment: @TheLocust911 see edit. It's too much to explain. Learn Lua doing normal tutorials then you'll understand what is going on those game related scripts and then you can modify them.

Comment: You've already gone far above and beyond, thank you! Back to studying I guess.